# Как присвоить коллекции новое значение через Stream Api?

Tags: java, java-stream

У меня есть коллекция и значение, по которому я хочу ее отфильтровать, выглядит это так:

```
StudyGroupPriorityQueue =
    StudyGroupPriorityQueue
        .stream()
        .filter(student ->
            student.getFormOfEducation()
                .equals(Enum.FormOfEducation.FULL_TIME_EDUCATION))
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(Queue<StudyGroup>));
```

IDE подчеркивает `collectionFactory`, а именно `Queue<StudyGroup>`, в чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Queue<StudyGroup>` просто тип, а `Collectors.toCollection` принимает объект-фабрику, например, ссылку на конструктор.

Судя по названию переменной вам нужна `PriorityQueue`

```
Collectors.toCollection(PriorityQueue::new)
```

Если объекты в StudyGroupPriorityQueue не реализуют интерфейс Comparable, то:

```
Collectors.toCollection(() -> new PriorityQueue<>(/*Comparator или его реализация*/comparator))
```

Comment: IDE говорит, что 'Queue' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Comment: так не получится. Queue - интерфейс. создать экземпляр интерфейса не получится

Comment: если нужна имплементация очереди, можно взять ArrayDeque, т.е. так toCollection(ArrayDeque::new)

Comment: @Ckafff забыл поменять на PriorityQueue, исправил

Comment: PriorityQueue имеет смысл, когда передаешь компаратор, это же очередь с приоритетом

Comment: @Дмитрий ну судя по названию переменной там и есть PriorityQueue с Comparable объектами

Comment: @Дмитрий,ArrayDeque ошибку не вызывает, но коллекция не изменяется

Comment: @ Ckafff не совсем понятно, что именно вы имете в виду. какая коллекция не изменяется?